# TensorFlow Assign

Tags: python, tensorflow, assign

I am trying to write a custom version of an RNN and would like to just store the state and last output of the cells in variables but it is not working.  My guess is that TensorFlow sees the storing of the values unnecessary and does not execute it.  Here is a snippet that illustrates the problem.

For this example, I have five layers of "cells" that intentionally ignore the input and output the sum of the biases for the cell and the previous output, which is initialized to zero.  However, as we run this, the output of the network is always just the values of the biases in the final layer and the value of `last_output` remains zero.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def cell_function(cell_inputs, layer):
    last_output = tf.get_variable('last_output_{}'.format(layer), shape=(10, 1),
                                  initializer=tf.zeros_initializer, trainable=False)
    biases = tf.get_variable('biases_{}'.format(layer), shape=(10, 1),
                             initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)
    cell_output = last_output + biases
    last_output.assign(cell_output)
    return cell_output

def rnn_function(inputs):
    with tf.variable_scope('rnn', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
        next_inputs = inputs
        for layer in range(num_layers):
            next_inputs = cell_function(next_inputs, layer)
    return next_inputs

num_layers = 5
data = np.random.uniform(0, 10, size=(1001, 10, 1))
x = tf.placeholder('float', shape=(10, 1))
y = tf.placeholder('float', shape=(10, 1))


predictions = rnn_function(x)
loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(predictions=predictions, labels=y)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1).minimize(loss=loss)


with tf.variable_scope('rnn', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
    last = tf.get_variable('last_output_4', shape=(10, 1), 
                           initializer=tf.zeros_initializer, trainable=False)
    layer_biases = tf.get_variable('biases_4', shape=(10, 1),
                                   initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    for t in range(1000):
        rnn_input = data[t]
        rnn_output = data[t+1]
        feed_dict = {x: rnn_input, y: rnn_output}
        fetches = [optimizer, redictions, loss, last, layer_biases]
        _, pred, mse, value, bias = sess.run(fetches, feed_dict=feed_dict)
        print('Predictions:')
        print(rnn_predictions)
        print(last.name)
        print(value)
        print(layer_biases.name)
        print(bias)
```

If change the last line of `cell_function` before the return to `last_output = tf.assign(last_output, cell_output)` and then return it with `cell_output` and then return it again out of `rnn_function` and use that for the variable `last` everything works.  I think it is because we are forcing TensorFlow to compute that node in the graph.

Is there any way to make this work without passing `last_output` out of the cell?  It would be much nicer if I didn't have to keep passing all this stuff out to get the assignment operation to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Make it dependent on an operation that will be run, in this example I'll use the cost function, but use whatever makes sense:

```
with tf.control_dependencies(cost):
  tf.assign(last_output, cell_output)
```

Now the assign operation will be required in order for `cost` to be computed, which should solve your problem. For any operation you request tensorflow to compute with `sess.run(some_op)`, tensorflow will work backwards through the dependency graph and only compute the minimum elements necessary to produce the requested output.